# Micronaut not picking thread from separate event-loop group for client call while calling using RXHttpClient?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, netty, micronaut

I was trying to understand, how the Micronaut/Netty thread model working under the hood. I create a simple project in which i have two service `product-service` and `recommendation-service`. I call the recommendation-service to show us the recommended product and `recommendation-service` call the product service to get the products via `RxHttpClient`. As per the micronaut documentation-> section-> 7.6 if we configure separate eventloop group for client call then it will pick the thread from that eventloop for all the client calls , but it does not seems working like that.

Thread Stack trace :

I used the `siege` to send concurrent request as :

`siege -c 5 -r 1 http://localhost:9009/recommendations`

```
16:54:49.408 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - RecommendationController.getRecommendations() called...
16:54:49.408 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - RecommendationController.getRecommendations() called...
16:54:49.408 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - RecommendationController.getRecommendations() called...
16:54:49.918 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - RecommendationController.getRecommendations() called...
16:54:49.918 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - RecommendationController.getRecommendations() called...
16:54:50.001 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-002) executed...
16:54:50.001 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-003) executed...
16:54:50.001 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-001) executed...
16:54:50.127 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-001 ready to return...
16:54:50.194 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-002 ready to return...
16:54:50.247 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-002) executed...
16:54:50.249 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-004) executed...
16:54:50.442 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-002 ready to return...
16:54:50.444 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-001) executed...
16:54:50.565 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-001 ready to return...
16:54:50.567 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-003) executed...
16:54:50.604 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-003 ready to return...
16:54:50.606 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-001) executed...
16:54:50.727 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-001 ready to return...
16:54:50.729 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-002) executed...
16:54:50.920 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-002 ready to return...
16:54:50.922 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-004) executed...
16:54:51.170 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-003 ready to return...
16:54:51.176 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-004) executed...
16:54:51.455 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-004 ready to return...
16:54:51.458 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-001) executed...
16:54:51.582 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-001 ready to return...
16:54:51.586 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-004) executed...
16:54:52.127 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-004 ready to return...
16:54:52.131 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-004) executed...
16:54:52.381 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-004 ready to return...
16:54:52.387 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-003) executed...
16:54:52.792 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-004 ready to return...
16:54:52.798 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-002) executed...
16:54:52.993 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-003 ready to return...
16:54:52.993 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-002 ready to return...
16:54:52.999 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-002) executed...
16:54:53.000 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-001) executed...
16:54:53.123 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-001 ready to return...
16:54:53.195 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-3] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-002 ready to return...
16:54:53.333 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-004 ready to return...
16:54:53.338 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-003) executed...
16:54:53.939 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-003 ready to return...
16:54:53.943 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductController - ProductController.getProduct(PROD-003) executed...
16:54:54.548 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.ProductService - Product with id PROD-003 ready to return...
```

If you notice in thread stack trace event for client call, the threads are being picked from  default-nioEventLoopGroup not from other group that we have defined in application.yaml as below:

```
  application:
    name: NIO-Sample-App
  server:
    port: 9009
    context-path: /
    max-request-size: '100MB'
    multipart:
      enable: true
      max-file-size: '100MB'
  http:
    client:
      event-loop-group: client1
      read-timeout: 5m
      timeout: 5m
      max-content-length: '100MB'
  netty:
    event-loops:
      default:
        num-threads: 3
      client1:
        num-threads: 2
```

Other Project files :

Product.java

```
package com.igaurav;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;

@JsonDeserialize(using = Product.Deserializer.class)
public final class Product {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    public Product(String id, String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, product.id) &&
                Objects.equals(name, product.name) &&
                Objects.equals(price, product.price);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, name, price);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product {" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }

    static class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Product> {

        @Override
        public Product deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            final JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
            return new Product(
                    node.get("id").asText(),
                    node.get("name").asText(),
                    new BigDecimal(node.get("price").asText())
            );
        }
    }
}
```

ProductClient.java

```
package com.igaurav;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.reactivex.Maybe;

@Client("/product")
public interface ProductClient {

    @Get("/{id}")
    Maybe<Product> getProduct(final String id);
}
```

ProductController.java

```
package com.igaurav;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.reactivex.Maybe;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller("/product")
final class ProductController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);

    private final ProductService productService;

    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @Get("/{id}")
    public Maybe<Product> getProduct(String id) {
        log.info("ProductController.getProduct({}) executed...", id);
//        try {
//            Thread.sleep(10000);
//        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        return productService.findProductById(id).onErrorComplete();
    }
}
```

ProductService.java

```
package com.igaurav;


import io.reactivex.Maybe;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@Singleton
final class ProductService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductService.class);

    private static final Map<String, Supplier<Product>> products = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    static {
        products.put("PROD-001", createProduct("PROD-001", "Micronaut in Action", 29.99, 120));
        products.put("PROD-002", createProduct("PROD-002", "Netty in Action", 31.22, 190));
        products.put("PROD-003", createProduct("PROD-003", "Effective Java, 3rd edition", 31.22, 600));
        products.put("PROD-004", createProduct("PROD-004", "Clean Code", 31.22, 1200));
    }

    public Maybe<Product> findProductById(final String id) {
        return Maybe.just(id)
                .map(it -> products.getOrDefault(it, () -> null).get());
    }

    private static Supplier<Product> createProduct(final String id, final String name, final Double price, final int latency) {
        return () -> {
            simulateLatency(latency);
            log.info("Product with id {} ready to return...", id);
            return new Product(id, name, BigDecimal.valueOf(price));
        };
    }

    private static void simulateLatency(final int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

RecommendationController.java

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient;
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Controller("/recommendations")
final class RecommendationController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecommendationController.class);

    private static final List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(
            "PROD-001",
            "PROD-002",
            "PROD-003",
            "PROD-004"
    );

    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer server;

    private final ProductClient productClient;

    public RecommendationController(ProductClient productClient) {
        this.productClient = productClient;
    }

    @Get
    public Single<List<Product>> getRecommendations() throws MalformedURLException {
        log.info("RecommendationController.getRecommendations() called...");
        RxHttpClient client = RxHttpClient.create(new URL("http://" + server.getHost() + ":" + server.getPort()));
        //Single<Product> s = client.retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/persons/reactive"), Product.class).firstOrError();
        return Observable.fromIterable(ids)
                .flatMap(id ->client.retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/product/"+id), Product.class)
                        .firstOrError()
                        .toObservable())
                .toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on what I see, none of your loggings are suppose to execute in the custom event loop. If you want to make sure of that, you could enable http client logging by `logger.levels.io.micronaut.http.client=DEBUG`.